# How to make image as same size as of text in html

Tags: html, css

i want the text as same size as image , how to get this???

this is the body i am using, how to get text as same size as text?

```
<body>
  <a href="https://github.com/ashutosh7i" style="font-family:trebuchet ms">My Github
    <img src="github.png" style="width:37px;height:37px;" /> </a><br>

</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Decrease height of image as much as it look same size as text height.

Comment: i tried this method, but then image and the text are not at same level or say same plane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your `<img>` element is set to `display:inline-block`.

Use relative units like `em` or `%` for height to scale your image according to it's parent font-size.
In this way, your image behaves similarly to an icon font.

```js
let range = document.querySelector('input')
let p = document.querySelector('.p')

range.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  let val = e.currentTarget.value;
  p.style.fontSize = val + 'px'
})
```

```html
<p>Font-size: <input type="range" min="12" max="100" step="2" value="16"></p>
<p class="p" style="font-family:'trebuchet ms';">My Github <img style="display:inline-block; height:1em; width:auto; transform:translate(0, 0.1em)" src="data:image/png;base64,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
  " alt=""> ashu</p>
```

You can also refine the baseline position by a `transform:translate()` value. E.g:

```
  transform: translate(0, 0.1em)
```

will move your image slightly beneath the baseline.

BTW. this approach would also work for inlined `<svg>` icons.

Comment: This gets the work done,hense declaring it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

That image doesn't look like an image. It looks like the Github icon from font-awesome. If it is an image, then I suggest you switch over to font-awesome.

Here's an example and this will keep everything the same height. It's not the greatest thing to mess around with images. Font-awesome treats fonts like a font, so you can control them with selectors and properties like font-size, etc.

```css
.fa-brands.fa-square-github {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h2>
  <a href="https://github.com/ashutosh7i" style="font-family:trebuchet ms">My Github
    <i class="fa-brands fa-square-github"></i> ashu 
  </a>      
</h2>
```